Meaning of "5er Handicap"
I was watching a German movie (Zum Glück gibt's Schreiner) where the discussion goes in the following lines:

Male Character: Was findet ihr Frauen an so Typen ? 
Female character: An attraktiven, gut verdienenden Ärzten und Philanthropen mit 911er Porsche und 5er Handicap ?

The female character is trying to explain the things that she found attractive in a particular man. But I was unable to understand what "5er Handicap" means.
And what would be the most appropriate translation in English ?

In this context, a handicap is a term from golf rules.
It is denoted by a numerical value, where the lowest values are the most desirable ones and indicate high skill at playing golf.
To judge handicap values, I have looked for a couple of resources that are hopefully somewhat representative:

What is a Good Handicap in Golf? - "A general rule of thumb is to aim to work towards a single digit handicap. (...) A handicap under 10 is usually indicative of a golfer that has been playing the game for a while."
What Does a Good Handicap Really Mean in Golf? - "The average handicap of female golfers is 28, and the average handicap of male golfers is 16"

Based on these, and some more sites with similar statements, I assume that a handicap of 5 must indicate quite a high skill level at golf (for most degrees of professionality at least).
From this, we can conclude that just like the other attributes:

attractive
decently earning
doctors
philantropic
owning a 911 Porsche car

all of which can be assumed to be seen positively, having a "handicap of 5 at golf" is meant as a positive attribute. Not only is the person in question playing golf (which, in itself, tends to be associated with desirable properties such as above-average financial means), they are also relatively good at it.

A handicap of 5 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicap_(golf)).
Some additional characters.

Also Wiktionary. Somehow I don't think of Germany as a big golfing country, but apparently there are more than 1000 courses there. Iceland has the most courses per capita, with a course for every 5000 people. Off-topic but I thought it was interesting.

Could you please add a sentence or two to describe it instead of just a link to Wikipedia ?

@Vpal No, I don't see what anyone would gain from that.

@Stefan: The gain is that your answer can be understood without relying on the ability to open a link to an external website.

@O.R.Mapper, Vpal My recommendation would be to use your ability to open a link to an external website, or research it in some other way. All you need to know is that "handicap" is a golf term and that this is the meaning in the quote. If you want to write about golf in another answer, please go ahead. I'm not going to do it for you.

Downvote for refusing to give a self-contained answer which is the norm on all Stackexchange sites I'm familiar with.

@Stefan Please include the relevant content from your link in the answer. This is part of how we define "a good answer", see https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer If the link contains no content at all that is relevant to the answer, why is it in the answer in the first place?

On a different note, getting rude leads nowhere.

Concise answers are great. This is too concise

@Jonathan O. R. Mapper has already written a more detailed answer, and I think it's pretty good. So what do you want from me? If the presence of less detailed answer offends you, delete it. The link to Wikipedia is just a way of saying "it's a golf term, you can look it up". In my eyes, that completely answers the question, which is why I didn't write it as a comment. I just wanted to help out the OP without writing an essay. If a comment would have been more acceptable, please let me know.

@Jonathan I don't think I was rude, but I was and am annoyed at people asking me to do something they could easily do themselves if they want it done. I'm not an employee here.

I think people just wanted to inform you about the policy that answers should be self-contained. One reason is that the content of a linked page is not guaranteed to be stable, and your answer's quality is at risk of deteriorating over time. The underlying assumption of the comments is that we are all here to help, and want to maximize the value of our contributions. It is perfectly fine to disagree. It is also fine to keep your post unchanged. Nobody wants to force you to do anything, people were asking and suggesting. Against your intent, your comment comes across as slightly rude, though.

I appreciate your contributions. I appreciate that you use your free time to help others here with your answers. It's people with that mindset who keep this community alive and thriving in the first place. I wanna emphasize that this wish to help others is a thing we all have in common here. If you could see the comments that were annoying you as an effort to collaborate, rather than the voice of a boss telling you what to do, it would be a step towards a great mindset that makes the community grow - wider and deeper.
